# net: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when accessing web api from angular2 application

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have setup my backend Web API created in VS2015 in the IIS server and I can access it via URL

> http://192.168.137.15:53610/

I have ng-build --prod my frontend angular2 application and served it using `http-serve` inside the dist folder which I access via URL

> http://192.168.137.15:8080/index.html

If I access the frontend in my pc, I can access the webapi so I can login. But if I access my frontend from a LAN, I can access the frontend because I can get to the login screen. But as soon as I click the submit button, I get the error of

> OPTIONS http://localhost:
>   polyfill.4afb43cdae.....bundle.js:153610/token
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

. Can you please show me how to do this right. Thank you.

Comment: According to the error message, it seems you have send option request to localhost instead of the http://192.168.137.15:53610/. I suggest you could check you angular codes to make sure you send the request to right url.

Comment: Thanknyou. You're right. It was pointing to the wrong IP.

Comment: If you feel my comment is right, I will write a reply. Please mark it as answer and it will help other people who faces the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message, it seems you have send option request to localhost instead of the 192.168.137.15:53610. I suggest you could check you angular codes to make sure you send the request to right url.